# Complicated Formula Issue adding specific values based on a parameter

Tags: excel, sorting, excel-formula

I have a table A and table B. Table A is the input table and table B is the output table. Table A has 2 Columns; `Name` and `Quantity`, and table B also has 2 Columns `Name` and `Quantity`, but the difference is that table B already has 48 names written inside it and the `Quantity` section is empty, And the whole of table A is empty. I'm not doing a very good job of explaining stuff. I know but if you are with me so far then.

Now I go to table 1 and put in the following data in the syntax `[Name,Quantity] : {Sam,10},{Lilly,15},{Sam,25}`. After putting in that data, I want the appropriate quantity cell in table B corresponding to the names to be equal to the total quantity each name has in table B.

In this case I want the output of table B show me `{Sam,35},{Lilly,15}` and the rest of the `Names = 0`.

I would prefer if this method stays in the terms of excel formula calculations and no macros or VBA as it will be easier for me to integrate this with the other functions of the spreadsheet I'm making. But I would not mind having alternatives.

Comment: Does table B contain those names from the beginning or you need to check if they are already there and if not add them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data format is like this:

[image]

You could use either SUMIF or a Pivot Table
If you use SUMIF, then you could list all the names with zero's.
If you use a Pivot Table, a list of names will be generated automatically.

For SUMIF, if the Quantity column of Table B starts in B2, you could use a formula like:

```
=SUMIF(Table_A[Name],A2,Table_A[Quantity])
```

and fill down to last row.
If Table A is not a "real" table, just substitute the range references for the appropriate columns.

Results of the SUMIF method:

[image]

If you want to use a Pivot Table, then with the cursor in Table A, select Insert / Pivot table.  Then drag Name to the Row Labels area, and Quantity to the Values area.  Format to taste.